# При отправке email пропадают немецкие буквы из заголовка

Tags: php, email, кодировка

```
function send_message($email, $message_title, $message_text) {
    $subject = $message_title;
    $from = EMAILER_ADDRESS;
    $nam = EMAILER_NAME;
    $mailheaders  = "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf8 \r\n";
    $mailheaders .= "From: $nam <$from>\r\n";
    $message = $message_text;

    $sms_result=mail("$email", stripslashes($subject), stripslashes($message), $mailheaders);
    return $sms_result; 
}
```

В некоторых сервисах пропадают буквы типа "ü" или "ö" из заголовка

Comment: а в какой кодировке сама строка передаёться?

Comment: В кодировке  UTF-8

Comment: некоторые сервисы их и не поддерживают, есть такое. Заменяйте на двухбуквенные варианты перед отправкой: "ü" на "ue", "ö" на "oe", и т.д. Это нормальная практика в Германии.